# How to populate dynamic options for multiple Selects inside a ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, servicenow

*I am adding dynamic rows by clicking "add Row" button in an Html form. In a row, I have 'Country' select and 'State' select. Whenever i select country, states are populated properly in first row and in second row onward if i change country all other row values are also changing. Please help.
In the below code , "data.states" array, i am loading from database. but the problem is among multiple rows, **states array is getting overridden** for each country change.*

```
 <table>
       <tr>
         <th>Country</th>
         <th>State</state>
         <th>Action</th>
       </tr>
       <tr ng-repeat="model in models track by $index">
          <td>
               <select ng-options="country in countries" ng-model="country" ng-change='getState(country)'>
               </select>
          </td>
          <td>
              <select ng-options="state in data.states">
              </select>
          </td>
          <td><button ng-click="addRow()">Add Row</button></td>
       </tr>
    </table>

$scope.models = [{}];

$scope.addRow = function(){
  $scope.models.push({});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that all your code is using the same ng-model reference for the country and also, you're not using different variables on the scope to store your states for each country in here: `<select ng-options="state in data.states"></select>`

Try the code bellow

```
    <table>
       <tr>
         <th>Country</th>
         <th>State</th>
         <th>Action</th>
       </tr>
       <tr ng-repeat="model in models">
          <td>
               <select ng-options="country as country for country in countries" ng-model="model.country" ng-change='getState(model.country)'>
               </select>
          </td>
          <td>
              <select ng-options="state as state for state in getState(model.country)" ng-model="model.state">
              </select>
          </td>
          <td><button ng-click="addRow()">Add Row</button></td>
       </tr>
    </table>


  $scope.models = [{}];

  $scope.countries = ['Brazil', 'Canada', 'US'];

  $scope.states = {
    Brazil: ['Rio de Janeiro', 'Acre', 'Bahia'],
    Canada: ['Ontario', 'Alberta', 'Manitoba'],
    US: ['California', 'Florida', 'Texas'],
  }

  $scope.addRow = function(){
    $scope.models.push({});
  }

  $scope.getState = function(country){
    // implement your fetch state logic here
    return $scope.states[country];
  }
```

Here's a working plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/coh5niQXon10l5RHYKza?p=info

Comment: With out "ng-change=getState(model.country)" also , the code is working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because you are using the same ng-model for all of your selects

```
ng-model="country"
```

if you want to select country independently in each row you can try the following

```
<tr ng-repeat="model in models track by $index">
    <td>
        <select ng-options="country in countries" ng-model="model.country" ng-change='getState(model.country)'>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select ng-model="model.state " ng-options="state in data.states">
        </select>
    </td>
    <td><button ng-click="addRow()">Add Row</button></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Hey, i didn't put that in question but doing the same thing, still not working

Comment: @viswa can you create a plunker please

Comment: Hi, I never tried plunker or any other. let me do that and update the question.